# UIImageView moves or resizes when I set the image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I created a UIImageView in interface builder. I retrieve an image via a urlrequest and then call setImage: with the UIImage. Unfortunately this causes the UIImageView to change its position on the screen and frame size

Answer (score 55):

I am assuming that the image that you are retrieving has a different size than that of the UIImageView.

Setting "Scale to fill" in IB will cause your image to stretch to fill completely you UIImageView, which depending on your content may not be desirable.

"Aspect fill" should fit and clip the image, but for this to work with images set programmatically, you must also check "clip subviews" in IB. If you don't your UIImage will overflow the bounds of the UIImageView.

Comment: Man, this deserves more attention than it's getting, and certainly to be marked as the correct answer. I, at least, didn't (and still don't) intuitively see the UIImage as being a subview of UIImageView on which the clipping would have any effect.

Comment: btw. programmatically it's `view.clipsToBounds = YES`

Comment: It's 2014 and this bug still exists... If you set the mode to Aspect Fill it should not need to also clip the subviews...

Comment: Great answer "clip subviews" +1

Comment: 2015 and still the same bug. Ridiculous.

Comment: I voted for you, because you mentioned to check "Clip Subviews", and that did the trick ;)

Comment: I was not able to fix this issue. However, setting the border type to "Photo" changes the behaviour so it did not resize.